# Prioritize NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

I have an `NSTimer` running. The app is doing a lot of things concurrently with the `NSTimer` (including in the same view controller as well as the app delegate). I cannot figure out why, but sometimes the `NSTimer` pauses and does not update a label. (It acts as a stop watch of sorts for the user.)

Should I try to figure this out using Instruments? To use global `dispatch_async()` for thing being called while it is being interrupted? Or is there a way to prioritize the NSTimer and the method it calls?

I'm creating the timer like so:

```
oneSecondTicker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                                                   target:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(updateLabelsWithOneSecondTicker) 
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:oneSecondTicker forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode]; //!important
```

Comment: We would need to know a) how you are creating the timer and b) what you are doing in the timer. Otherwise we can only guess at what is really happening.

Comment: Is the method called by NSTimer on the main thread? You might want to ensure that any code that updates the UI is called on the main thread.

Comment: yes i am allocing the timer in viewDidLoad... the timer is an instance variable of the VC class.  Currently: oneSecondTicker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabelsWithOneSecondTicker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Comment: oh and : [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:oneSecondTicker forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode]; //!important

Comment: You don't need to use `-[NSRunLoop addTimer:forMode:]` it if you're creating it with `scheduledTimer...`

Comment: @rickerbh how would I perform this action on the main thread?

Comment: The `scheduledTimer...` methods add the timer to the run loop as part of the creation process.

Comment: In your code that updates UI... `[myViewObject performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(uiChangingMethod:) withObject:someObject wait:YES]`